# accessing nested list in JSONArray

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I have created a `JSONObject` from a raw JSON string. Then I created a `JSONArray`from it. I am trying to access the `"location"` list for each index of the `JSONArray` because I need the `"location"` information for the `Location` constructor.
[image]

This is what I have so far

```
try
{
    //create a JSON Object with the raw string
    JSONObject json=new JSONObject(responseData);
    //create array of businesses
    JSONArray arr=json.getJSONArray("businesses");
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
    {
        //I need "location" info here
        locations.add(new Location(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"), arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_url"),"placeholder",0));
    }
}
catch (JSONException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my answer was more than obvious but somehow I complicated myself. This worked for me.

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject loc=arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location");
    locations.add(new Location(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"), arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"), arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_url"),loc.getString("address1")+" "+ loc.getString("address2")+","+loc.getString("city")+","+loc.getString("zip_code"),0));
}
```

Comment: try using an array.map() operation that is faster